# Javascript SVG curve change path attirbut C

Tags: javascript, svg, path, attributes, set

Thank you in advance.
i try to move un SVG curve element in html using javascript.
I would like to change the path of my svg so that my blue curve transforms like the red curve but with the transition to see the displacement of the curve.
i understand how to get or create an element but i am not sure how to set the attribude 'd' like change every 'c' in path.

```js
alert(document.getElementById('s3').getAttribute('d'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


    <svg viewBox="0 0 990 180" height="200" width="1100" id="mySVG">

        <g> 
            <path id="s2" d="M 241,128 C 272,113 293,152 369,125 C 434,80 471,72 580,114  " 
            fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px" />

            <path id="s3" d="M 241,128 C266,131 298,100 369,125 C 441,150 482,151 580,114  " 
            fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5px" />
           

        </g>

    </svg>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your question: If you want to animate from one curve to the other you can use SMIL animations.

Since the paths in your code have the same number and the same type of commands you can use an `<animate>` element to animate the d attribute.

The `values` attribute is a list of values separated with semicolons (;) The first and the last value is the d attribute of the curve. The second value is the d attribute of the other one.

In my code the duration of the animation is 5 seconds: `dur="5s`

```html
<svg viewBox="235 80 350 70" width="300" id="mySVG">

  <g>
    <path id="s2" d="M 241,128 
             C 272,113 293,152 369,125 
             C 434,80 471,72 580,114" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px">

    </path>

    <path id="s3" d="M 241,128 
             C266,131 298,100 369,125 
             C 441,150 482,151 580,114" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5px">
      <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML" values="M 241,128 
             C266,131 298,100 369,125 
             C 441,150 482,151 580,114;    
                 
             M 241,128 
             C 272,113 293,152 369,125 
             C 434,80 471,72 580,114;
                 
             M 241,128 
             C266,131 298,100 369,125 
             C 441,150 482,151 580,114; " dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </path>

  </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> can i make it in javascript?

Making it in javascript is more complicated. You will need to set an array of values and an array of target values and recalculate each value of the curve with every frame of the animation. Next comes an example that is animating the blue curve on click:

Please read the comments in the code.

```js
//I've hard coded the values and the target array
//you may want to do it dimamicaly from the d attribute

let vals = [
  ["M", 241, 128],
  ["C", 272, 113, 293, 152, 369, 125],
  ["C", 434, 80, 471, 72, 580, 114]
];

let target = [
  ["M", 241, 128],
  ["C", 266, 131, 298, 100, 369, 125],
  ["C", 441, 150, 482, 151, 580, 114]
];

//the request animation id
let rid = null;
//build the memory array used for the animation
let memory = [];
for (let i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
  memory[i] = [];
  memory[i][0] = target[i].slice();
  memory[i][1] = vals[i].slice();
}

function Frame() {
  rid = window.requestAnimationFrame(Frame);
  updateValues();
  updatePath();
}

window.addEventListener("load", updatePath, false);


// I'm animating the curve on click
svg.addEventListener(
  "mousedown",
  function () {
  // if there is an animation running stop it before start another one
    if (rid) {
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
      rid = null;
    }
    
    //reverse the animation
    for (let i = 0; i < memory.length; i++) {
      memory[i].reverse();
      target[i] = memory[i][1].slice();
    }
    //call the Frame function
    Frame();
  },
  false
);

function updateValues() {
//a function to update all the values of the curve except the move to part that is not changing anyway
  for (let i = 1; i < vals.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j < vals[i].length; j++) {
      let dist = target[i][j] - vals[i][j];
      let vel = dist / 10;
      vals[i][j] += vel;
    }
  }
}
//a function to reset the value of the d attribute
function updatePath() {
  let d = `M${vals[0][1]},${vals[0][2]}`;
  for (let i = 1; i < vals.length; i++) {
    d += `C${vals[i][1]},${vals[i][2]},${vals[i][3]},${vals[i][4]},${vals[i][5]},${vals[i][6]}`;
  }
  s3.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="235 80 350 70" width="300" id="mySVG">
  <g>
    <path id="s2" d="M 241,128 
             C 272,113 293,152 369,125 
             C 434,80 471,72 580,114" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px">
    </path>
    <path id="s3" d="M 241,128 
             C266,131 298,100 369,125 
             C 441,150 482,151 580,114" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="5px">    
    </path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution but can i make it in javascript ?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what I want, I am starting to create something in that way but perfect job.